# WPF DataTemplate method binding with parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatemplate

I have a custom ItemTemplate for a ListBox and I need to "bind" a TextBlock to some special method / property.

My ListBox Source is an `ObservableCollection<SearchResultItem>`. `SearchResultItem` containing some properties.

The text need to change based on the value of another object. E.G if this object equals "foo" I need the text value to call the method `GetProperty("foo")` on the `SearchResultItem` to get the correct value.

Here is a sample of code:

```
<DataTemplate>
..
//Here is a Label bound to the Date Property of the SearchResultItem
<Label Margin="2,2,2,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding Path=Date}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
//Here is the textblock that needs to call the method with the parameter based on the value of the other object.
<TextBlock Margin="2,2,2,0" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="I need some help there" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black"/>
..
</DataTemplate>
```

Do you have any idea on how to do that or a better way to do it?

Edit:

-Let's assume `SearchResultItem` comes from an external library and only exposes the `GetProperty` method.

-Let's say the "foo" value comes from `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["propertyName"];` if it helps.

Comment: Have you tried using a converter?

Comment: I've seen some example of code using a converter, but I don't know how to access the "foo" object value this way.

Comment: You say you have a DataTemplate for a custom ListBox, but what I think you're trying to say is that you have a custom ItemTemplate for the ListBox...am I correct?

Comment: @Ryan you're right,I edited the OP

Comment: @DannyWillem, ok so once a SearchResultItem is added to the collection, can the properties' values ever change?

Comment: Nope the properties never change. I've Edited the OP to add some more details

Comment: What is the "type" of the object you're comparing to "foo", a string?

Comment: The SearchResultItem basically contains a Dictionary<string, string> which is a mapping Property Name / Property Value. If the value is "foo" I'd like to display the value corresponding to the key "foo" in the SearchResultItem's Dictionary.

Comment: @DannyWillem did any of the answers solve your issue? If so, please mark one.

Comment: @Ryan I'll give a try to Dean Chalk's answer tomorrow and then validate either yours or his depending which one I succeeded with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, because your properties never change, here's one solution. You can do this via another property on your SearchResultItem class:

```
public string MyTextBinding
{
    get 
    {
        return myDictionary.ContainsKey("foo") ? return myDictionary["foo"] : return "myDictionary doesn't contain foo"; 
    }
}
```

Then just bind your textbox to this property:

```
<DataTemplate>    
    <Label Margin="2,2,2,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding Path=Date}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
    <TextBlock Margin="2,2,2,0" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=MyTextBinding, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I can't do that, because SearchResultItem comes from an external library and it doesn't know about "foo".

Comment: You could write a wrapper for it that contains your SearchResultItem and change your ObservableCollection to a collection of these wrappers

Comment: I was thinking of that but I don't like the wrapping idea too much. I was thinking of a binding / xaml solution. Indeed if no other solution is proposed I'll go ahead and wrap my item.

Comment: But you will be binding still...just to a wrapper class instead of your SearchResultItem. I'm not sure what kind of solution you had in your mind, but since SearchResultItem only exposes the GetProperty method, you'll need some wrapper so you can call that method from code and return that value in your binding property

Comment: I finally went with the wrapper! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `IValueConverter` that takes a `SearchResultItem` and return the expected text

```
<TextBlock Margin="2,2,2,0" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" 
           Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
           Text="{Binding Path=., 
                Converter={StaticResource PropertyValueFromSearchResultItemConverter}, 
                ConverterParameter=Foo}" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black"/>
```